# Realtime searching in Angular with RxJS tap vs subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a server side query in an Angular form. I do the search with the following RxJS code.The results will be used to update a table.

1. I want the query to happen when the search word is greater than 3 characters as well as when there is no search string. Can I achieve this with only a conditional statement `searchTerm?.length == 0`?
2. I have a query that is shown at the bottom is achieved with `tap` statement. Is there any side effect if I don't do the server side call `this.getContacts(search);` inside `subscribe`?
3. Is there a method to achieve the same without the `subscribe`?

```
@ViewChild('input') input?: ElementRef;
```

```
fromEvent(this.input?.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        pluck<unknown, string>('target', 'value'),
        filter((searchTerm: string) => (searchTerm?.length > 2 || searchTerm?.length == 0)),
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
      )
      .subscribe(search => {
        this.getContacts(search);
      });
```

With `tap` statement:

```
fromEvent(this.input?.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        pluck<unknown, string>('target', 'value'),
        filter((searchTerm: string) => (searchTerm?.length > 2 || searchTerm?.length == 0)),
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
      )
      .tap(search => {
        this.getContacts(search);
      })
      .subscribe();
```

Comment: Is getContacts() an asynchronous server call? If so, I'd recommend using a switchmap instead of using the tap or nesting in a subscribe.

Comment: getContacts() is an async call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that getContacts is an async call, but I imagine that your function getContacts() will be like

```
getContact(search)
{
   this.httpClient(....).subscribe(res=>{
       this.data=res;
   })
}
```

See that, in this case you has "two subscribes". A suggest is to have the less subscribe as was possible. So imagine your getContacts return an Observable, some like

```
getContact(search)
{
   return this.httpClient(....)
}
```

See that there're no subscription

So you use switchMap. switchMap reemplace one observable for another one, so you can has

```
fromEvent(this.input?.nativeElement, 'keyup')
  .pipe(
    pluck<unknown, string>('target', 'value'),
    filter((searchTerm: string) => (searchTerm?.length > 2 || searchTerm?.length == 0)),
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(search=>{
       //not return "search" else this.getContacts(search)
       return this.getContacts(search);
    }
  )
```

The before is an observable so to execute you need **subscribe always**.

```
fromEvent(this.input?.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
   ..).subscribe(res=>{
       this.data=res; //<--in subscription you equal the response to a variable
   })
```

And your .html

```
   <div *ngfor="let item of data>
     ...
   </div>
```

Or, if you want you can use pipe async (pipe async makes a subscription), so you use a variable

```
data$=fromEvent(this.input?.nativeElement,'keyup').pipe(
 ...)
```

And in .html

```
   <div *ngfor="let item of data$|async>
     ...
   </div>
```

But yes, always you need subscribe

About the "tap" operator, the aim of this operator generally is for make a log or a cache (tap not change the response)